# Check for type in Plone PythonScript

Tags: python, plone, zope

I'm trying to check a variable for its type in a Plone Products.PythonScript.
I tried this code:

```
if isinstance(var, list):
    do(sth)
```

Unfortunately, 'list' and 'type' are restricted in a PythonScript. I got this error:

```
 TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

Is there any possibility to check my variable for its type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python Script can use a special function [`same_type()`](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/BasicScripting.html#built-in-functions) to work around the restrictions set on types:

```
if same_type(var, []):
```

where we use the literal empty list notation, not the `list` type itself (since that has been reassigned).

Comment: After working with it a few more days, I have to annotate that it just works with `if same_type(var, [])`, not with `if same_type(var, list)`. `list` is still restricted. :)

Comment: Right, I'll update; the literal syntax has not been overridden then.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your issue is as described.

That error seems to indicate that you've assigned the variable `list` to something else (which you shouldn't do).

eg:

```
>>> l = range(4)
>>> list = 'something'
>>> isinstance(l,list)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
>>>
```

**EDIT:**  According to the [Plone website](http://plone.org/documentation/faq/restricted-python-scripts), *Zope 2 "Python Scripts" are outdated technology and you should no longer write any Plone code through Zope Management Interface using Python scripts. Instead, create an add-on and create Zope 3 browser views in it.*

Comment: I've never assigned a variable `list` . If I check for `list`, I get `<AccessControl.ZopeGuards.GuardedListType instance at 0x3c14950>`

Comment: @Maphardam: ah, yes, list objects have been replaced by a special proxy object instead.

Answer (score -1):

How about this, based on http://developer.plone.org/functionality/expressions.html#python-expression ? You could try sth like

```
expression = Expression("if isinstance(var, list): myflag=True")
expression_context = getExprContext(self.context)
value = expression(expression_context)
```

Comment: good idea, but it is not allowed to import Products.CMFCore.Expression

Comment: This doesn't address the issue at all; `Expression` objects are also restricted Python expressions.